Manhwa about a man who, right as he is about to die, goes back in time to the day before the zombie apocalypse
The man was on top of a bunch of cars on a highway before going back in time.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/return-survival?

https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/41eftkd/dreamcide?

Is this Mortals of the Doom...?

Zuo Tianchen is the last living human in a mutated zombie-infested city. Just when he was sure he'd died, he finds his soul returned to just before that ill-fated day ten years ago. He swears he'll protect the people important to him this time round and reunite with his past lover. Watch his struggles to survive equipped with his memory of the next ten years!

The story begins in the year 2028, ten years after a meteorite brought a virus to Earth, triggering a zombie apocalypse. Zuo Tianchen, the last man alive in his city, is sitting on top of a pile of cars, having run out of supplies and ammunition, and makes his last stand as he's swarmed by hundreds of zombies. He then wakes up back in his high school classroom, 90 minutes before the meteorite struck.
You can read the manhua at MangaToon and the web novel at WebNovel.

